# Install Custom Dependency for KFP Op

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I'm trying to setup a simple KubeFlow pipeline, and I'm having trouble packaging up dependencies in a way that works for KubeFlow.

The code simply downloads a config file and parses it, then passes back the parsed configuration.

However, in order to parse the config file, it needs to have access to another internal python package.

I have a `.tar.gz` archive of the package hosted on a bucket in the same project, and added the URL of the package as a dependency, but I get an error message saying `tarfile.ReadError: not a gzip file`.

I know the file is good, so it's some intermediate issue with hosting on a bucket or the way kubeflow installs dependencies.

Here is a minimal example:

```
from kfp import compiler
from kfp import dsl
from kfp.components import func_to_container_op
from google.protobuf import text_format
from google.cloud import storage
import training_reader

def get_training_config(working_bucket: str,
                        working_directoy: str,
                        config_file: str) -> training_reader.TrainEvalPipelineConfig:
    download_file(working_bucket, os.path.join(working_directoy, config_file), "ssd.config")
    pipeline_config = training_reader.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
    with open("ssd.config", 'r') as f:
        text_format.Merge(f.read(), pipeline_config)
    return pipeline_config

config_op_packages = ["https://storage.cloud.google.com/my_bucket/packages/training-reader-0.1.tar.gz",
                      "google-cloud-storage",
                      "protobuf"
                      ]
training_config_op = func_to_container_op(get_training_config,
                                          base_image="tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.2-py3",
                                          packages_to_install=config_op_packages)

def output_config(config: training_reader.TrainEvalPipelineConfig) -> None:
    print(config)

output_config_op = func_to_container_op(output_config)

@dsl.pipeline(
    name='Post Training Processing',
    description='Building the post-processing pipeline'
)
def ssd_postprocessing_pipeline(
    working_bucket: str,
    working_directory: str,
    config_file:str):
    config = training_config_op(working_bucket, working_directory, config_file)
    output_config_op(config.output)

pipeline_name = ssd_postprocessing_pipeline.__name__ + '.zip'
compiler.Compiler().compile(ssd_postprocessing_pipeline, pipeline_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `https://storage.cloud.google.com/my_bucket/packages/training-reader-0.1.tar.gz` IRL requires authentication. Try to download it in Incognito mode and you'll see the login page instead of file.
Changing the URL to `https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket/packages/training-reader-0.1.tar.gz` works for public objects, but your object is not public.

The only thing you can do (if you cannot make the package public) is to use `google.cloud.storage` library or `gsutil` program to download the file from the bucket and then manually install it suing `subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', ...])`

Where are you downloading the data from?

What's the purpose of

```
    pipeline_config = training_reader.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
    with open("ssd.config", 'r') as f:
        text_format.Merge(f.read(), pipeline_config)
    return pipeline_config
```

Why not just do the following:

```py
def get_training_config(
    working_bucket: str,
    working_directory: str,
    config_file: str,
    output_config_path: OutputFile('TrainEvalPipelineConfig'),
):
    download_file(working_bucket, os.path.join(working_directoy, config_file), output_config_path)
```

> the way kubeflow installs dependencies.

Export your component to loadable `component.yaml` and you'll see how KFP Lighweight components install dependencies:

```py
training_config_op = func_to_container_op(
    get_training_config,
    base_image="tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.2-py3",
    packages_to_install=config_op_packages,
    output_component_file='component.yaml',
)
```

P.S. Some small pieces of info:

> @dsl.pipeline(

Not required unless you want to use the `dsl-compile` command-line program

> pipeline_name = ssd_postprocessing_pipeline.**name** + '.zip'
>   compiler.Compiler().compile(ssd_postprocessing_pipeline, pipeline_name)

Did you know that you can just `kfp.Client(host=...).create_run_from_pipeline_func(ssd_postprocessing_pipeline, arguments={})` to run the pipeline right away?